# Запись html сайта в локальный файл

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, urllib

у меня есть парсер он выводит код сайта но я хочу чтоб помимо вывода кода он записывал этот код сайта

сам код:

```
myUrl = 'http://www.astahov.net'
otvet = request.urlopen(myUrl)
mytext1 = otvet.readlines()
mytext2 = otvet.read()
print(otvet)
print(mytext2)
for line in mytext1:
    print(line)
filetxt = open('txtfile.txt', 'w')
filetxt.write(line(str(mytext1)))
filetxt.close()
```

но он не записывает туда код сайта почему ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если так попробовать?

```
from urllib import request

myUrl = 'http://www.astahov.net'
otvet = request.urlopen(myUrl)
mytext1 = otvet.readlines()
filetxt = open('txtfile.txt', 'wb')
for line in mytext1:
    filetxt.write(line)
filetxt.close()
```

Comment: нет не работает ((

Comment: исправил ответ, проверил - работает

Comment: режим записи файла `wb`

Comment: Ооо заработало Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Адаптирую код из вопроса:

```
from urllib import request

with request.urlopen('http://www.astahov.net') as f:
    mytext2 = f.read()

...

with open('txtfile.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(mytext2)
```

Либо без разделения. Считываем с сайта страницу и сразу записываем в файл:

```
from urllib import request

with request.urlopen('http://www.astahov.net') as f:
    mytext2 = f.read()

    with open('txtfile.txt', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(mytext2)
```